# How to delete a document from collection using Mongodb Aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections. Locations and Archiveloc. I would like to enter particular document to archiveloc from locations after passing some conditions. And then, that particular document is needed to be deleted from the Locations collection after transferring it to Archiveloc. I could transfer documents to Archiveloc but cannot delete that from Locations collection. Below is my code

```
locations.aggregate([
        {
            $sort: {
                createdAt: -1
            }
                },
        {
            $group: {

                _id: '$imei',
                total_imei: {
                    $sum: 1,


                },

                "firstDoc": {
                    "$first": "$_id",

                },
                object: {
                    $push: "$$ROOT",


                },


            }
                },



        {
            $match: {

                total_imei: {
                    $gt: 2
                }
            }
                },

        {
            $out: "archiveloc",

                        }



    ].exec(function (e, d) {
        console.log(d);
        d.forEach(function (data) {

            console.log(data);
            // return temp;
            // console.log(temp);


        });

    }));
```

Quick help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

For test purpose, example of documents is provided below:

For the collection called Locations:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57010cde76fe39110d716ad0"),
"sourcedevice" : "tcpping",
"imei" : "86669902366722",
"commandtype" : "AAA",
"latitude" : "0.41995433112606406",
"longitude" : "0.43301976611837745",
"datetime" : ISODate("2016-04-03T12:30:22.401Z"),
"status" : "A",
"mileage" : "10418109",
"run_time" : "12854934",
"base_station_info" : "470|1|61E0|43C4",
"io_port_status" : "0000",
"analog_input" : "0000|0000|0000|02D3|010A",
"increment_index" : 1459686622401.0000000000000000,
"__v" : 0}
```

Documents for Archiveloc collection:

```
{
"_id" : "86669902366722",
"total_imei" : 45,
"firstDoc" : ObjectId("57010cde76fe39110d716ad0"),
"object" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57010cde76fe39110d716ad0"),
        "sourcedevice" : "tcpping",
        "imei" : "86669902366722",
        "commandtype" : "AAA",
        "latitude" : "0.41995433112606406",
        "longitude" : "0.43301976611837745",
        "direction" : "83",
        "horizaontal_accuracy" : "0.8",
        "altitude" : "6",
        "mileage" : "10418109",
        "run_time" : "12854934",
        "base_station_info" : "470|1|61E0|43C4",
        "io_port_status" : "0000",
        "analog_input" : "0000|0000|0000|02D3|010A",
        "increment_index" : 1459686622401.0000000000000000,
        "__v" : 0
    }
]}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to post sample MongoDB documents for both collections for test run.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Have added documents for test run.

Comment: Have you checked ttl feature in Mongo ? https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

Comment: It is easier to remove documents that way.

Comment: @nobody, this is applicable only if I put expire date, but according to my condition, the document will be deleted when it is transferred to "archiveloc" collection.

Comment: What do you meant by "cannot delete " in question ? Do you have an error ? I don't see the delete part in your code. After being copied to target collection do you mark the collections with some flag, as copied successfully or something ? Or do you assume that all collections in source collection need to be copied ? If I was doing this, I would probably copy and mark the copied collections with some copiedAt timestamp attribute, which would be indexed and follow the expiration approach above.

Comment: @nobody, i want to use delete in aggregation process, however, I dont find any query for removing documents from collection. Btw, I like the way you approach to solve the problem..Let me try it...Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @shumanachowdhury, your query doesn't return anything. yes, I removed $out stage from aggregation pipeline. If you want iterate over aggregation result, remove `$out` stage, iterate over result, insert document manually in loop to other collection and then delete from source.

Comment: You cannot delete or update through aggregation, aggregation is an advanced version of querying where at each stage you get some data but at no stage any of those data is being updated back to DB, if you get the result from aggregation and delete yourself, that's another story.